# Search item in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, struct, find

I want to find an element (surname) in my struct

```
struct student
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int marks;
};
```

Ofc define vector and searching element from keyboard

```
vector <student> v;
char search_surname[20];
```

I am input elements by function:

```
    int size = v.size();
    v.push_back(student());
    cout << "Input name: " << endl;
    cin >> v[size].name;
    cout << "Input surname: " << endl;
    cin >> v[size].surname;
    cout << "Input marks: " << endl;
    cin >> v[size].marks;
```

Now, when I have for example three surnames in my struct (newton, einstein, pascal), I want to find surname newton and cout all details of struct with newton (name, surname, marks). I have no idea what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute-force method:

```
for(vector <student>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
{
    if (strcmp(it->surname, "newton") == 0)
    {
        cout << "name = " << it->name << endl;
        cout << "surname = " << it->surname << endl;
        cout << "marks = " << it->marks << endl;
    }
}
```

Please add `#include <cstring>` to your code in order to use `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

With STL, you may use `std::find_if` from `<algorithm>`:

```
std::vector<student> v;


auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const student& s)
              {
                  return strcmp(s.surname, "newton") == 0;
              });
if (it != v.end()) {
    std::cout << "name = " << it->name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "surname = " << it->surname << std::endl;
    std::cout << "marks = " << it->marks << std::endl;
}
```

Note: I suggest to use `std::string` instead of `char[20]` and so condition would become `return s.surname == "newton"`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used  std::find()  from library < algorithm >

This function returns an iterator, and indicates found when the return value is not end().